# I need some clarification on the MVC architecture and the three-tier architecture

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, repository-pattern, 3-tier

I've been reading the book Pro ASP NET MVC Framework and I'm getting really confused with a lot of things. I've been trying to do some research but I'm finding that with so many different approaches and concepts being thrown at me, it's just making things worse.
So I have a few questions:

1. I know MVC is supposed to split the functionality into three main things: Model -> Controller -> View. Is the MVC a different approach than the three-tier architecture? Or am I still supposed to be thinking of creating a Data Access Layer and a Business Logic Layer in my project?
2. What exactly are Repositories? It is what acts as my Data Access Layer? Where/How do Repositories fit into the MVC?
3. The book talks about using LINQ to SQL to interact with the database but yet it states that LINQ to SQL will not be supported in the future and that Microsoft is dropping it for the Entity Framework. Where does the Entity Framework fit into the MVC and how do I interact with it?

Thanks in advance for your help!
Matt

Comment: LINQ to SQL is ~NOT~ being dropped and it states as much in your book on Pg. 49.

Comment: Also, in terms of difference between MVC and Three-Tier, I suggest you re-read pg. 41 specifically the last paragraph at the top.

Comment: I did see that it was going to be included in ASP.NET 4.0, but I assumed it was still slowly being dropped.

Okay, yes I did read that paragraph. Like I said, with all the terms and concepts being thrown at me at once I'm getting a bit confused and forgetting some of the things I've read. Thanks.

Comment: @Matt, I'd say this isn't the best book for real beginner in the field.  Not that it isn't a good book, I really enjoy it.  But "Pro ASP.NET MVC" is just that, a book more geared towards veterans.  I think I'd be confused also if I hadn't been introduced to most of these concepts repeatedly in the past.

Comment: @Matt, LINQ is here to stay with us for a long time. Entities is nice, but it isn't like most people won't be using LINQ to Entities anyway, so learning and using LINQ isn't a bad option at all.

Comment: @Matt, or instead of buying the other book (which still is a good idea), you can take a look at this demo by Scott Gu on NerdDinner, afterwards you can proceed to your book at hand. http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Intro.htm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. MVC is mostly a pattern for the presentation layer, and it focuses on the interaction between the view and the controller. The model can be considered to be [the components of the application that are responsible for maintaining state](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/10/14/asp-net-mvc-framework.aspx), including persistence.

   In a simple application the model might just be an LINQ-To-SQL model. In a large enterprise application the model might contain a data access layer, business layer, and a domain layer. The ASP.NET MVC does not restrict you to how the M should be implemented.
2. The [Repository](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) pattern is one way to implement the persistence part of the M. The [ActiveRecord](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) is another. Which pattern to choose depends on the complexity of the application, and your preferences.

   Take a look at [Step 3](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part3.htm) of the NerdDinner tutorial where they create a simple repository using Linq to SQL.
3. Linq to SQL will not be dead. Microsoft will still improve the core and add customer requests where it makes sense but Entity Framework would be the primary focus. Take a look at this post for [LINQ to SQL changes in .NET 4.0](http://damieng.com/blog/2009/06/01/linq-to-sql-changes-in-net-40).

   The EF can be used is a similar way as LINQ to SQL, but it is also more flexible so it can be used in other ways. For example EF4 will more or less support persistence of your own POCO objects in a more Domain Driven Design.

Comment: very informative answer.  I should be able to vote this answer up 3 times!

Answer (score 6):

Yes, I think MVC is a different approach than "the" 3-tier architecture that I think you meant here (the architecture where you create mainly 3 projects DAL, BL, and UI). The main idea behind MVC is the separation of concerns between each of its components (Model, View and Controller). The controller is the component responsible for handling user requests, and in most cases it corporates with the "Model" component in order to display the desired view as a response to the user request. The difference between this and the traditional 3-tier architecture, is that the DAL, and the BL are grouped now and named a Model and **yes you still need to create these components.** 
What are repositories? 
[Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) mentions the definition of a repository as **"Mediates between the domain and data mapping layers using a collection-like interface for accessing domain objects"** Repositories are part of your data access layer, they don't access data by themselves, they mediate between the domain and the data mapping entities, and of course they should be placed in your Model folder/project.

Will Linq to SQL be deprecated? 
**NO** and the same book states so, also Damien Guard ( a developer at the ADO.NET team) mentioned in one of his blog posts that Linq to SQL will be included in .NET 4.0.

How to interact with EF?
As you would with Linq to SQL. Like Linq to SQL, Entity Framework will be your mapping entities, and will reside in the Model project as well.

 Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're a bit confused over these things, and they *are* confusing, so let's go over them slowly.

1. **N-Tiered Architecture and MVC are different, but intertwined.** N-Tier usually talks about separating Data Access, Business Logic and the User Interface. However, some people may argue that it is impossible to totally separate BLLs from the UI; MVC addresses that, in such a way that there is a corresponding Controller talking to your BLL, and to your View, as opposed to having your View talk directly to your BLL.
2. **Yes, having repositories is one approach to having a DAL**. There are many ways of doing this, and you should not limit yourself to what is discussed in the book.
3. **The book only uses LINQ to SQL to demonstrate ASP.NET MVC the fastest way possible, but it is NOT the only way.** Stop thinking about LINQ to SQL for a minute; ASP.NET MVC can be used whether you use an ORM like NHibernate or you use plain ADO.NET + DAL Factory or whatever -- what you'll not going to be able to use are those ASP.NET `ObjectDataSources` that you drag and drop with your UI.

As for Entity Framework, Brad Abrams wrote a nice guide on [how to use Entity Framework with ASP.NET MVC](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2008/01/29/asp-net-mvc-example-application-over-northwind-with-the-entity-framework.aspx), that should cover your last question.

HTH

Answer (score -1):

1. Yes you still need to create data access and business logic layers yourself. Some may argue that the Controller layer **IS** the business logic but I personally prefer the separation between real business logic (e.g. pricing calculation) from screen business logic (e.g. event handler for the "OK" button). You will then call these from your Controller class. The controller class controls the logic for your screen and manages the translation from your data/business logic layer to the screen value.
2. the ASP.NET MVC framework puts no restriction on the "Model" layer, which means you can use whatever you want including NHibernate, LINQ to SQL or entity framework. I use LINQ to SQL because it's simple.
3. Not sure, never read that book. I just downloaded Scott Hanselman's Nerddinner project from codeplex and use that as a guide for writing ASP.NET MVC websites.

Comment: Its all about persistence layer in your second point, not the Model layer, arguably may be.

Comment: First of all I call it the "Model" layer because this question is about MVC. Secondly, like I said in my point 1, I handle "business logics" in the "Model" layer too so it is _NOT_ just about persistence.

Comment: Its very much confused. I mean I never heard of this separation "screen business logic" and "real business logic". Why simply say business logic and presentation logic, and then it would become model and view. I handle business logic in Model too, but how can it include persistence, was my point. It goes as a separate layer, if not then a bad practice indeed.

Comment: And BTW if you don't find persistence answered by MVC, so you will attribute it to M. I don't get the point.

Comment: Put it this way, if you put all your business logic in the Model layer, how do you reuse it in another program? Does that mean you have to add reference to the Website from your program so you can call the method? it doesn't make sense does it?

Comment: All those details regarding the web will not be the part of Model, but of View. Because that is not business logic, but the presentation logic and details. Now, I hope you can use your model with some different view technology.

Comment: @Vinegar. The persistence is answered by the ASP.NET MVC, it is part of the M. Scott Gu (the architect of ASP.NET MVC) wrote ""Models" in a MVC based application are the components of the application that are responsible for maintaining state.  Often this state is persisted inside a database"

Comment: Suppose Swing API in Java, its based on MVC, and there is no persistence. But since the question is specifically about ASP.NET, and generally about the web application, we must discuss it in the same context. As far as the mentioned excerpt is concerned, I am very much in the accord. The idea, that Models are persisted in databases, doesn't mean that the persistence layer is the part of Model. It merely means that Models are persisted in databases, and it can be using some data layer which is external to Models. I mean, its okay and not contradictory to any of my understanding.

Comment: Another example can be Spring MVC Framework, which doesn't provide anything for persistence in its MVC framework. There is the very useful JDBC API in Spring, but that is in Spring core, not as a part of MVC.

Comment: @Vinegar ASP.NET MVC is basically the same, the model layer is basically empty when you first created a MVC project, nothing gets generated and you get to choose whatever you want to use for your Model layer. Someone jokingly said ASP.NET MVC is really just ASP.NET VC